# Android Toolbar show/hide blank space

Tags: android, android-actionbar, toolbar

I'm trying to have my toolbar hide or show when the user is scrolling a list. To do it, I'm using a translation but a blank space appears instead of my actionBar. If I use a setVisibility(View.GONE), the blank space will appear during the animation and hide when it's done which is ugly..

[Here is a short video of my issue](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_afm_-4pcbA&feature=youtu.be)

And here is how i do my animation (from Google I/O app) :

```
public void showToolbar(boolean show){
    if (show) {
        toolbar.animate()
                .translationY(0)
                .alpha(1)
                .setDuration(HEADER_HIDE_ANIM_DURATION)
                .setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
    } else {
        toolbar.animate()
                .translationY(-toolbar.getBottom())
                .alpha(0)
                .setDuration(HEADER_HIDE_ANIM_DURATION)
                .setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
    }
}
```

And here is my layout :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/mainContent">

<include layout="@layout/toolbar"
    android:id="@+id/my_toolbar" />

<fragment
    android:name="com.ar.oe.fragments.SectionsFragment"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And my toolbar

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
/>
```

Comment: have you managed to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

You need animate your container and not your toolbar.

Try this:

```
RelativeLayout mainContent = (RelativeLayout) findById(R.id.mainContent);

public void showToolbar(boolean show){
if (show) {
    mainContent.animate()
            .translationY(0)
            .alpha(1)
            .setDuration(HEADER_HIDE_ANIM_DURATION)
            .setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
} else {
    mainContent.animate()
            .translationY(-toolbar.getBottom())
            .alpha(0)
            .setDuration(HEADER_HIDE_ANIM_DURATION)
            .setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
}
}
```

It work for me ;)

If you want to move your fragment with your toolbar, you need animate your fragment and not only your bar.

Comment: but it will make the blank space move from top to bottom and add effect bounce up and bounce down continously if we hold the finger when the animation happens

Comment: any solution how to remove black space at bottom?

Answer (score 1):

It is better that you show slide up translate animation for both toolbar and your below fragment (together), when user is trying to scroll, such that only toolbar goes out of the view and fragment reaches the top. (within say, 200ms). To do this, translate the whole outer Relative Layout by say some 20% (you can change such that only toolbar goes out of the view) :

Add slide_up.xml in your anim folder :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">  
   <translate 
    android:fillAfter="false"
    android:fromYDelta="0%" 
    android:toYDelta="-20%" 
    android:duration="200"/>

</set>
```

Then, when scroll event is triggered, do the following :

```
 ...
 RelativeLayout rel = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainContent);
 Animation slideUp = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.slide_up);
 rel.startAnimation(slideUp);
 ...
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: This will still have the same amount of black space but at BOTTOM...! But is there a way to tell the container (fragment) to stick to the bottom of Toolbar and keep updating the layout so as to keep it sticking to toolbar bottom?

Comment: any solution how to remove black space at bottom?